# C++/CLI and C#: object returns itself

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Given a class `Object`, it's possible in C++ to return a reference to the object itself like:

```
    //C++
    class Object
    {
        Object& method1()
        {
            //..
            return *this;
        }
        Object& method2()
        {
            //.
            return *this;
        }
    }
```

And then consume it as:

```
    //C++
    Object obj;
    obj.method1().method2();
```

Is it possible to achive the same effect in C++/CLI and use it in C# application? I've tried the following (with refs `%` and handles `^`), which compiles in C++/CLI, but C# says that such methods are

> is not supported by the language

```
    //C++/CLI - compiles OK
    public ref class Object
    {
        Object% method1()
        {
            //..
            return *this;
        }
        Object% method2()
        {
            //.
            return *this;
        }
    }
```

Then use as:

```
    //C#
    Object obj = new Object();
    obj.method1(); //ERROR
    obj.method1().method2(); //ERROR
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need the following for C++/CLI:

```
public ref class Object
{
public:
    Object ^method1()
    {
        //..
        return this;
    }
    Object ^method2()
    {
        //.
        return this;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Dave, just figured this out as well :) Marking your answer as correct!

Answer (score 0):

OK, this worked fine:

```
//C++/CLI - compiles OK
public ref class Object
{
    Object^ method1()
    {
        //..
        return this;
    }
    Object^ method2()
    {
        //.
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then use as:

```
//C#
Object obj = new Object();
obj.method1();
obj.method1().method2();
```